# How to find a path whose sum of weight is minimum when negative weights are present?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This question derive from [How to find a longest path, which contains as many vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136277/how-to-find-a-longest-path-which-contains-as-many-vertices),which is a solved problem.But I don't very happy with it based on a brute force method.So I try to built a negtive weight value since the documentation(**ref/FindShortestPath-Examples-Scope-Specification**) of [`FindShortestPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestPath.html) say:

[image]

The graph is

```
g=Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
  10}, {SparseArray[Automatic, {10, 10}, 
   0, {1, {{0, 2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 18, 
      20}, {{3}, {4}, {1}, {6}, {8}, {5}, {9}, {2}, {9}, {2}, {6}, 
{3}, {5}, {7}, {8}, {4}, 
           {1}, {8}, {1}, {3}}}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}], Null}, {VertexLabels -> {"Name"}}]
```

[image]

But this code get nothing:

```
FindShortestPath[
   Graph[g, EdgeWeight -> Table[-1, EdgeCount[g]]], ##] & @@@ 
 Tuples[Range[9], 2]
```

It's seem the `FindShortestPath` don't support the weight of negtive value.But as I know,the weight can be any value of real-number.Any method to do this by it or `FindMinimumCostFlow` [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112221/21532)?

Comment: @Feyre The path's sum of weight is minimum?

Comment: I made a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the reason why `FindShortestPath` returns unevaluated is that your graph contains cycles. If there is a cycle with total negative weight, certain shortest paths will not exist. The path can always be made shorter (i.e. have a more negative total weight) by going around the cycle one more time.

Most, perhaps all, of the nodes in your graph are part of at least one cycle. Thus a shortest path having them as an endpoint does not exist (in the sense that for any path you choose there is always a shorter one—none of them are *the shortest*).